# How to put url into variable when button clicked

Tags: javascript

I've tried several things for days... so i whittled this down to save time...
I want to click the CopyQQ button, and have the url... ex https://www.TestURL.com/pt/595564 copied into a var.  see code below...
I realize that I need to somehow use the e.target, but beyond that, (as a newby to js), I'm just now quite sure how to grab the url field that i need...

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  This is head<br>
</head>
<body>
  This is body<br>

<form>

<div class=thelist>

<ul>

<l>  
<br>
  <div class="fj43">
    <button class="fjCopyTxtButton" onclick="copyURL()">
    CopyQQ
    </button>
    https://www.TestURL.com/pt/595564
  </div>
<br>
</l>

<l>
<br>
  <div class="fj43">
    <button class="fjCopyTxtButton" onclick="copyURL()">
    CopyQQ
    </button>
    https://www.TestURL.com/pt/222222
  </div>
<br>
</l>

<l>
<br>
  <div class="fj43">
    <button class="fjCopyTxtButton" onclick="copyURL()">
    CopyQQ
    </button>
    https://www.TestURL.com/pt/333333
  </div>
<br>
</l>

</ul>

</div>

</form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function copyURL(e) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var aa = event.target.innerText
      console.log(aa)
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the URL, you need to read the content of the parent of `event.target`, this is done with [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement), then remove the text of the button from it, using [`string.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
function copyURL(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // get ALL the parent text, even button content
  const parentText = event.target.parentElement.innerText
  const buttonText = event.target.innerText
  // remove the text of the button from the parent text
  const url = parentText.substring(buttonText.length + 1)
  console.log(url)
}
```

```html
<div class="fj43">
  <button class="fjCopyTxtButton" onclick="copyURL()">
  CopyQQ
  </button>
  https://www.TestURL.com/pt/595564
</div>
<div class="fj43">
  <button class="fjCopyTxtButton" onclick="copyURL()">
  CopyQQ
  </button>
  https://www.TestURL.com/pt/222222
</div>
<div class="fj43">
  <button class="fjCopyTxtButton" onclick="copyURL()">
  CopyQQ
  </button>
  https://www.TestURL.com/pt/333333
</div>
```